# what would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Tags: java

```
float value = 0;
for (Foo foo : arrayList) {
    float temporaryValue = calculate(foo);
    if (temporaryValue < minValue) {
        continue;
    }   
    value = temporaryValue;
}
```

Is it possible to optimize for performance more in Java 8?
For example using a different iteration method or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, simplified your sequential code:

```
float value = 0;
for (Foo foo : arrayList) {
    float temporaryValue = calculate(foo);
    if (temporaryValue > minValue) {
        value = temporaryValue;
    }  
}
```

Then, if the number of elements on the ArrayList is high enough you can try to parallelize your code. First, make your method parallelizable:

```
static void some_method(float[] values, int threadID, int total_threads){
    float value = 0;
    float minValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i  = threadID; i < arrayList.size(); i+= total_threads) {
        float temporaryValue = calculate(arrayList.get(i));
        if (temporaryValue < minValue) {
            continue;
        }
        value = temporaryValue;
    }
   values[threadID] = value;
}
```

In the code above, each thread will be *only* responsible for finding the max from a chunk of the list (*i.e.,* `for (int i  = threadID; i < arrayList.size(); i+= total_threads)`). In the end, each thread updates, in the corresponded position of the array of values  (*i.e.,* values[threadID] = value;), the max value that it had found. This update should be done at the end to minimize potential false-sharing overhead.

Now create the threads, assign them work, and wait for them to finish.

```
    int total_threads = 2;
    float[] values = new float[total_threads];
    List<Thread> threads  = new ArrayList<>(total_threads);

    for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
        final int threadID = i;
        threads.add(new Thread(() -> some_method(values, threadID, total_threads)));
    }

    threads.forEach(Thread::start);
    threads.forEach(t -> {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    // Calculate the maximum
    float max_value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (float v : values) {
        max_value = Math.max(v, max_value);
    }
}
```

After every thread has performed their work and found their max value, the *main* thread will find from those values which one is the biggest:

```
float max_value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (float v : values) {
    max_value = Math.max(v, max_value);
}
```

You might want to further tune the distribution of iterations *per* thread:

```
 for (int i  = threadID; i < arrayList.size(); i+= total_threads)
```

depending on the content of the `calculate` method, it might pay off to use a *dynamic* loop distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove superfluous steps:

```java
if(temporaryValue > value) {
    value = temporaryValue;
}
```

Or simply `break` from the loop when you have a value >= `minValue`.

Alternatively use Java 8 streams:

```java
final float value = (float) arrayList
    .stream()
    .mapToDouble(this::calculate)
    .max();
```

This isn't likely to improve performance over the basic loop, in fact it's probably slower.  However streams can be easily parallelized (or at least considerably easier than custom multi-threading).

But tbh the first question you need to ask is do I need to optimise this code?  How big is your list?  How often is this code invoked?  How complex is the `calculate()` method compared to the iteration?

Comment: Turning a simple for loop into a stream isn't known for improving performances. If I believe what I've heard, it introduces a slight overhead. Parallelizing might help though.

Comment: the calculate method is pretty big, as in about 80 lines.

Comment: @Aaron Good point, I'll modify accordingly.

Comment: In that case, perhaps the calculate method is a better place for optimizations.  While the Streams API can simplify the code and make it more readable, I'd be surprised if you see any performance gains from doing just that.  Depending on the number of items in your list, multi-threading might help - but it introduces overhead that could actually increase processing time on a small list.

Comment: breaking out of the loop is my answer

Comment: @whollow Lines of code have no bearing on how 'fast' or not the code will run, though obviously complexity generally implies more work.  If you don't know where the problem is or even if there is a problem why are you spending time 'optimising' the code?

Comment: @RiaanNel The calculate method uses a lot of methods from minecraft because I use it to calculate the amount of damage a certain object deals, do not think it could be optimized that much.

Comment: @RiaanNel Also its mostly math related so JIT probably optimizes it aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Since the last value in the list that satisfies the criteria "wins", you could iterate backwards and break out of the loop as soon as the first value is greater or equal than min value. Assuming the calculate method has no important side effects.